# What happened to the term “stance”?

Tags: word-usage

While  checking with Google Books  the usage of the expressions ***[positive/negative stance on (something)](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=positive%20stance%20on%2Cnegative%20stance%20on&share=&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3://)***  I realized that they literally took off from the early 60s while their usage was quite rare before. And the term [stance](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=stance&corpus=26&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cstance%3B%2Cc0) used also in other  contexts appears to have had the same usage trend.

@JohnLawler suggests that stance is another term for stand, and actually [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=positive%20stance%20on%2Cnegative%20stance%20on%2Cpositive%20stand%20on%2C%20negative%20stand%20on&corpus=26&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpositive%20stance%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnegative%20stance%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpositive%20stand%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnegative%20stand%20on%3B%2Cc0) reveals a correspondence between the negative/positive expressions.  In other words from about the early 60s ”positive/negative stand on” usage has started to decrease while “negative/positive stance” usage increased. It appears that, for some reason, stance was preferred  to stand.

Can anybody suggest why “stance” has such an increase of popularity from those years? Was it used by some reputable journalist or politician who made its fortune?

Comment: Also note that the [spike in usage in BrE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=positive+stance+on%2Cnegative+stance+on&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=29&smoothing=3)  lagged AmE by around a year. My guess (although I cannot prove it) is that it had a little something to do with the social issues in the US at that time i.e. Vietnam, civil rights legislation, etc.

Comment: _Stance_ is just a variant of _stand_ (n), with the same metaphorical meaning. It would be interesting to compare the use of _stance_ during that period with _stand_ in similar contexts: _take a stand on_ vs _take a stance on_. There might well be tradeoff if there was a change in one.

Comment: @JohnLawler - the is actually an apparent correspondence between stand vs stance in the positive/negative expressions. It appears there was a switch between the two terms to some extent..why? https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?corpus=26&content=positive+stance+on%2Cnegative+stance+on%2Cpositive+stand+on%2C+negative+stand+on&smoothing=3&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpositive%20stance%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnegative%20stance%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cpositive%20stand%20on%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnegative%20stand%20on%3B%2Cc0

Comment: In the US, I'd say *stand* and *stance* have quite different connotations. The kids doing a sit-in in the dean's office were taking a stance. The fellows at the Alamo were taking a stand. I'm not sure *stand* is available unless there's a risk of being shot. Blame it on Custer, I guess.

Comment: @PhilSweet From what I recall of the times, the term "last stand" was re-purposed in the in the 60s in the form of "Custard's Last Stand" for road-side soft ice-cream drive-ins...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to agree with Phil Sweet in his comment that there is a nuance between take a stand - to mount a determined resistance, and take a stance -to take a position accompanied by various degrees of a defensive or aggressive attitude.

OED:

> **Stance**

**Etymology:** < French stance (now only in the sense ‘stanza’: see 4), < Italian stanza station, stopping place, room, etc.: see stanza n.(Show Less)
**1.a. A standing-place, station, position.**

> 1532   E. Boner in State Papers Henry VIII (1849) VII. 396   *Beyng at a stance, where oon way turneth to the Popes lodging, and the other to the Emperours, the Pope departed from the Emperour.*
>
> 1862   H. Beveridge Comprehensive Hist. India II. iv. iv. 143   *One chapter is devoted to..stances for deities.*

This then broadly remained the case until the late 19th century

> **1 d. In Golf and other games: The position of the player's feet in playing a stroke. Also transferred, the position of the player's body in readiness or in playing a stroke. Similarly gen., a standing attitude or way of positioning.**
>
> 1897   Outing 30 426/1   *The stance, the grip, the swing, that together make up, what they call a good style.*

In its turn "stance" then took on the meaning of

> e. ***figurative***. **An attitude adopted in relation to a particular object of contemplation; a policy, ‘posture’.**
>
> 1960   Amer. Speech 35 215   *An ‘unlinguistic’ stance is evidenced in the view that some variants embody language ‘corruption’.*
>
> 1977   J. I. M. Stewart Madonna of Astrolabe xx. 277   *Moderate regret and underlying unconcern established itself as our public stance.*

The 1960 quote above is the first recorded use of "stance" in this sense.

**Stand**(n.) is somewhat older:

> II. Place of standing.
>
> **11.a. A place of standing, position, station; also in phr. to take one's stand, poet. to take stand.**
>
> a1300   Cursor Mundi 1694   *Siþen efter alþernest hand þe meke beistes sal haue þair stand.*
>
> 1827   Scott Surgeon's Daughter in Chron. Canongate 1st Ser. II. iv. 114   *He saw from his lofty stand all the dumb show of gallantry.*

The difference is that the figurative use entered the language in the 16th century:

> **b. fig.**
>
> 1595   S. Daniel First Fowre Bks. Ciuile Warres iii. cxxv. sig. S2   *Nay father since your fortune did attaine So hye a stand: I meane not to descend, Replyes the Prince.*
>
> 1874   J. R. Green Short Hist. Eng. People vii. §4. 375   *He [Philip] was preparing..to take a new political stand as the patron of Catholicism throughout the world.*

It therefore seems that the replacement of **stand** with **stance** occurred with the popularisation of golf in the late 50s/early 60s.